# How to set an img tag with an id to false if the source is empty?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, show-hide

I am trying to set the visibility of an img tag with the id of #myComputer to false if the inner html doesn't have an image source assigned.

HTML

```
    <img id="myComputer" src="assets/myComputer.png">
```

JS

```
    var myComputer = document.getElementById('myComputer').src;
    var myComputerVisible = true;

    if(myComputer == ""){
    myComputerVisible = false;
    };
```

When I remove the source and check the console 'myComputerVisible' still shows as "true" even if I remove the source in the html:

```
    <img id="myComputer" src="">
```

Plain Javascript only. Please advise! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getAttribute` instead:

```js
var myComputer = document.getElementById('myComputer').getAttribute("src");
var myComputerVisible = true;
console.log("src is: " + myComputer);
if (myComputer == "") {
  myComputerVisible = false;
};

console.log(myComputerVisible);
```

```html
<img id="myComputer" src="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use getAttribute to get the value of any attribute of HTML tag.

```
 var myComputer = document.getElementById("myComputer").getAttribute("src");
```